# PHP array of objects - group by property

Tags: php, grouping

Iam having a difficult time grouping an array of objects by a property. I couldn't find a good answer on this one; might be that I'm tired; might be that I missed out on something essential here. 
Anyways - I have created an Employee class holding objects of employees. Including name, email, phone and department.
I would like to GROUP my array of employees by their department. So if I print out my array, everybody on sales will be grouped together.

Heres what it looks like now:

```
 $employees = array();
     while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $data = array(
    'name' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_name', true),
    'email' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_mail', true),
    'phone' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_phone', true),
    'department' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_department', true)
    );
    array_push($employees, new Employee($data));
endwhile;
```

And the Employee class:

```
class Employee
{

public $name;
public $email;
public $phone;
public $department;


public function __construct(Array $params = array()){
    if(count($params)){
        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried? And tell us where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$employees` would need to be an associative array, having the individual departments as it's keys.

Like this:

```
$employees = array();
while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $data = array(
      'name' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_name', true),
      'email' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_mail', true),
      'phone' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_phone', true),
      'department' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefix_department', true)
    );

    // Check if there is already an index for this department, or create it
    if(!isset($employees[$data['department']])) {
        $employees[$data['department']] = array();
    }

    // Assign the employee object to that key (department)
    $employees[$data['department']][] = new Employee($data));

endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Argh, I guess I need some fresh air. How could I possibly be this stupid? The isset thing, gosh I feel stupid. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll mark it as solved shortly :)